# spring-cloud-sleuth with Zipkin with Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm using spring-cloud's sleuth with zipkin with kafka.
here is my pom.xml configure.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

---

and ,the blew is my application.yaml:

```
kafka:
producer:
  bootstrap-servers:
  - 127.0.0.0:9092
  compression-type: gzip
  retries: 3
  batch-size: 100
  acks: all
  buffer-memory: 100
sleuth:
sampler:
  probability: 1.0
  zipkin:
compression:
  enabled: true
service:
  name: quoteCheckPlatform
sender:
  type: kafka
  message-timeout: 60
  enabled: true
```

---

and then, I start the spring boot application,try to access by browsers,but I can't find the spring cloud send sleuth  to kafka. So I try to debug the zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter, and find that every time the [flush] method return when go to line 265 which is "if (!bundler.isReady() && !closed.get()) return;"  the code show as below.

```
 void flush(BufferNextMessage<S> bundler) {
  if (closed.get()) throw new IllegalStateException("closed");

  pending.drainTo(bundler, bundler.remainingNanos());

  // record after flushing reduces the amount of gauge events vs on doing this on report
  metrics.updateQueuedSpans(pending.count);
  metrics.updateQueuedBytes(pending.sizeInBytes);

  // loop around if we are running, and the bundle isn't full
  // if we are closed, try to send what's pending
  if (!bundler.isReady() && !closed.get()) return;

  // Signal that we are about to send a message of a known size in bytes
  metrics.incrementMessages();
  metrics.incrementMessageBytes(bundler.sizeInBytes());
```

I know it means bufferFull is false.but why every time it is not bufferFull even if I try invoke the URL frequently?

thank you for attention.

Comment: Please use `Finchley.RELEASE` and set `spring.zipkin.sender.type: kafka`

Comment: thanks for advise.but there is no change.

Comment: Your yaml looks improperly formatted